# The application of a Fluid (air) cooler on 20mm product, equations for temperature, moisture content and relative humidity (maybe modelling)

Tags: control-engineering, airflow, modeling, cooling, evaporation

I currently have a fluid bed cooler which is cooling fine powder (around 20mm) product which enters upto 80 °C (minimum 40 °C) and leaves at a maximum of 25 °C. The mass flow rate is about 1200 kg/h. For the cooling part air pulled through a chilling fan with is set a 0 °C and enters the fluid bed at 9.3 °C and leaves at 11-40 °C depending on the temperature of the product. At the end of the line the moisture content and fat content is measured which I am looking to control/predict.

From my understanding I should measure the flowrates of air and the relative humidity of air in and out of the fluid bed cooler.
I can add flowmeters, relative humidity and temperature measurement but without knowing the equation I am not sure what and where to measure?

I am looking for equations on how relative humidity of air removes the moisture content of the product?

Comment: I think there should be some kind of equilibrium for a combination of certain moistures in the product and in the air above it. The farther the conditions will be from this, the faster the moisture exchange will be (greater driving force for the change).

Comment: It not so simple. You need to know about [Psychrometrics](https://www.ashrae.org/technical-resources/bookstore/psychrometrics).

Comment: If you know the air temperature, volume, and relative humidity you can determine the mass flow rate of water entering and leaving the fluid bed. Warm air holds MUCH more water than cold air at the same relative humidity.